# Find the sum of an array in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an array that holds integer values. And I have defined it like so:

```
@State private var numbers: Array = []
```

the array is updated as the user uses the app. At a certain point, I need to find the sum of all the values in the array. Here is what I tried to do:

```
let sumOfNum = numberz.reduce(0, +)
```

However, this is giving me the following error on the plus(+) symbol:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Int) -> Int' to expected argument type '(Int, Any) throws -> Int'
```

Not sure what the problem is. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: The appear to have an array of functions, not an array of ints (`[Int]`).  Use `@State private var numbers: [Int] = []` and you will see an error where you try use `(Int) -> Int` instead of just `Int`.

Comment: Is `@State private var numbers: Array = []` even valid? `Any` isn't just "assumed" like that, I don't think.

Comment: @Alexander Yes it is weird but SwiftUI does allow that. `private var numbers: Array { get nonmutating set }`

Comment: @George OP is using an array of Any. Thats what it is inferring when not explicitly setting the type. I have successfully reproduced the error here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably your Array declaration. You should declare is as an array of Int instead of an array of Any.

[image]

So your array declaration should be

```
@State private var numbers: [Int] = []
```

Comment: Thank you this solved the issue.